# generated .css file in nginx

Tags: nginx, css, cakephp, mvc

I developed on an apache, now I need to deploy on ngix and I ran into some difficulties. Because inline-styles are disabled in my project (with cakephp) and there are some colours defined in the database, I made the RsrcController generating the css with the colours into a template.

Calling this function works only if I don't use the file extension .css, but just the slashed Url with controller and function.

If I append the file ending .css, nginx is searching in the webroot folder and returns a 404.

This is the relevant part of the config:

```
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }


        #pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
           fastcgi_index   index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
```

I tried to find a solution adding another location rule like this:

```
location ~ rsrc/css_vars/~.css {
    ... [->second part of my question]
}
```

I dont want to pass all .css files to php. just those i expect to be dynamic generated. Anyhow, my changes dont seem to work.

Second part:

Cakephp works following way: http://url.com/controller/function/var1/var2/varx
My contoller is rsrc. My function is css_vars.
Than there are some vars (user...) and at the end I need the ".css".

I thought of rewriting the URl to the same but without the file extension ".css". Is there any way to come around regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented following solution:

```
#special for rsrc controller
location ~ ^/rsrc/css_vars/.*\.css$ {
   rewrite "^(.+)\.\w+$" "$1" last;
}
```

This is going to cut away .css from the request if the request is for rsrc controller and function css_vars.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this:

```
location ~ ^(/rsrc/css_vars/.+)\.css$ {
    rewrite ^ "$1" last;
}
```

It is a bit more efficient, since we trigger the regex engine only once, and capture the needed part in the `location` directive. I also changed this to not match `/rsrc/css_vars/.css` path, since the `*` version would have matched it also.